# R programming, glm() function

Tags: r

Whenever I try to run the following script,

`lm.fit <- glm(res~., data=train) #res is class of my dataset`

I get the following error

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

my dataset details:

15 variable, 10 of them are integer and 5 of them are factor.

Comment: That means you have a categorical variables in your data frame (factor or character) that has only a single value.

Comment: try `sapply(train, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) length(levels(x)) else NA)` to see where the problem is ...

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `neural-network` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you should check which one of your factors has less than 2 levels.

```
sapply(train, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) length(levels(x)) else NA)
```

Would do the job as said by Ben Bolker

Comment: yeah, it would work, i know. but then, what is the problem here: 
>lm.fit <- glm(res~., data=train)

Comment: First, what does the above code return when you run it?